# Profiling OpenGL ES in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, opengl-es

I'm trying to do some profiling on my OpenGL ES code. Somewhere in my GPU pipeline (a shader I believe) is causing a huge delay. Which is the best profiler I can use? Is [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/) one a good option? is there one I can use directly within Visual Studio?

Comment: How do you run GLES on windows ? Do you use a GLES emulator or EGL  features from AMD or Nvidia ?

Comment: I don't. It's part of a library that runs on an iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GPU performance issue on IOS, the best is to use XCode tools to profile it directly on device, running the app from Xcode and then doing a frame capture to look at the timings for each draw call / the number of cycles used by each shader (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html))

You can also profile on Windows if you are also able to simulate your graphics pipeline in classic OpenGL in your Windows version, but this may not be a good idea as the iPhone's GPU is very different than a classic desktop GPU so the bottleneck might not be the same on Windows than on IOS.

To profile on Windows I would suggest using either [Nvidia PerfKit](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit) (if you have a Nvidia card) or AMD's [GPU PerfStudio](http://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-perfstudio/) if you have an AMD card.

There is also [RenderDoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc) which is a nice tool but not sure if it provides much profiling information (it is more for debugging graphics issues than profiling)